# Carousel trazendo uma tabela com informações do banco de dados

Tags: javascript, html, css, banco-de-dados, carousel

é o seguinte eu queria saber se é possível colocar uma tabela para dentro do carousel, trazendo os dados de 5 em 5 linhas, quando completasse 5 linhas os próximos dados continuaria na página seguinte, funcionaria ai como uma paginação de uma tabela. eu tentei, porém só estou conseguindo paginar de uma em uma linha. Por favor pessoal me ajudem!!!

```html
<?php include'conexao.php'; ?>
<html>
    <head>
         
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" ></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" >
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        
    </head>
    <body>
    <div align="center">
        <form id="conteudo" >
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
           <?php
                $ctrAtivo = 2 ; 
                $ctrSlide = 1 ;
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM exames ORDER BY id ASC";
                    
                $resultados = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                
                while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados)){ 
          ?>
                   
                <?php  if($ctrAtivo == 2){ ?>
          
                     <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          
          <?php                                    
            $ctrAtivo = 1;                                  
          }else{ ?>
          
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $ctrSlide ?>"></li>
          <?php
              $ctrSlide++;
          }
            ?>  
        
          <?php
                            
                }
            
            ?>
          
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <?php
                $ctrAtivo = 2 ; 
            
          
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM exames ORDER BY id ASC";
                    
                $resultados = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                
                while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados)){ 
          ?>
                   
                <?php  if($ctrAtivo == 2){ ?>
          
                     <div class="item active">
                             <table border="1">
                
                                   <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo"$rows[paciente]"; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo"$rows[medico]"; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo"$rows[crm]"; ?></td>

                                   </tr>

                               </table>
                    
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                          
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
          
          <?php                                    
            $ctrAtivo = 1;                                  
          }else{ ?>
          
                <div class="item ">
                             <table border="1">
                
                                   <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo"$rows[paciente]"; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo"$rows[medico]"; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo"$rows[crm]"; ?></td>

                                   </tr>

                               </table>
                    
                      <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                          
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>   
          
          <?php
          }
            ?>  
        
          <?php
                            
                }
            
            ?>
          
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
        </div>
          
    </div>
    
     </form>
     
     
</div> 
    
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: já tentou utilizar mysqli_fetch_all em vez de mysqli_fetch_assoc?

Comment: Sim amigo, deu erro. mas na verdade eu queria trazer 5 linhas por cada página do carousel. Mas fico grato pela sua sugestão.